# I want search for multiple keyword in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to search for shad and chavhan in name column using mysql query
Data is 
name
Shadab
Rakesh chavhan

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "...WHERE name='shad' OR name='chavhan'..."

Comment: "Data is name `Shadab Rakesh chavhan`" `..WHERE name LIKE '%shad% OR name LIKE '%chavhan%'` is more likely @Ilias

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM YourTableName Where name like '%shad%' Or name like '%chavhan%';
```

I'm not sure what you want to do as the question itself isn't that much understandable but if you meant by searching for name or string than this would be best idea.